Efficient Null-Safe Division in Spark
I have a PySpark transformation that is taking longer to complete than I was expecting, and when I dug into the timing I found that it was this division that was slowing the whole process down;
df.withColumn(
    "null1", F.col("col1").isin([None, float("nan"), 0])
).withColumn(
    "null2", F.col("col2").isin([None, float("nan"), 0])
).withColumn(
    "ratio",
    F.when((F.col("null1") | F.col("null2")), F.lit(None))
        .otherwise(F.col("col1") / F.col("col2")),
).drop("null1", "null2")

Other than this division, everything else is executing quickly; There are no joins, maps or loops in this particular transformation to slow things down.
I am wondering if there is any way to do this kind of check and divide in PySpark that is significantly more efficient than what I have here? I tried the try_divide function, but that was no faster (and not quite the same performance).
Thanks for any help.

How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example
